# Bits of a Character in Java

Tags: java, io, utf

As I know `a` is an 8 bits character, `â` is a 16 bits character:

1. How to know a character is 8 bits or 16 bits or higher?
2. Why `â` character could not present at 8 bits?
3. `a` or `â` just UI form, how do they look like in bits form?
4. 97 is the code of `a`, how to calculate this number or it's just the ordinal number of character?

Comment: You have a lot of assumptions wrong, the first of which is that 'a' is "8 bits". It is not. A `char` in Java is 16 bits, always -- and it's a UTF-16 code unit, to be precise.

Answer (score 5):

> As I know `'a'` is an 8 bits character, `'â'` is a 16 bits character.

Not really. Java `char` is an unsigned 16-bit type, so both `'a'` and `'â'` are 16-bit characters. It is true that `'a'`'s top 8 bits are set to zero, but these bits are there nevertheless. Same goes for `'â'` (see below).

> How to know a character is 8 bits or 16 bits or higher?

Compare `ch & 0xFF00` to zero. If it is zero, the upper 8 bits are all zeros; otherwise, some of these eight bits are non-zeros.

> Why `'â'` character could not present at 8 bits?

It can be presented as using 8-bit: `'â'`'s code is 0xE2, or 226. It fits in 8 bits, but it does not fit in 7 bits. Here is a convenient [table](http://unicode-table.com/en/) for looking up character codes.

> `'a'` or `'â'` just UI form, how do they look like in bits form?

Since `char` is an integral type, you can convert it to `int` and print them in binary, decimal, hex or other radix to see the bit patterns behind the character representations.

> 97 is the code of `'a'`, how to calculate this number or it's just the ordinal number of character?

Cast `'a'` to an `int`:

```
int a = (int)'a';
```

Comment: Cast `'a'` to an `int`, I have known that, but I mean what is the meaning of 97 how does it differ with 97 in match?

Comment: @HoangNguyen 97 is simply a number that gets *interpreted* as a character `'a'` when it is set to a variable of type `char`. Apart from this interpretation, there is no difference from ninety-seven-the-int and ninety-seven-the-char.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvinient, do `'a'` in `UTF-8` and `'a'` in `UTF-16` have the same code 97?

Comment: @HoangNguyen Yes, all printable characters that can be encoded as a single byte in UTF-8 have the same lower byte and zero upper byte in UTF-16.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, my number two question. To know a character is `8bits` or not, could I `cast char to int` to get the code and then compare the code with the maximum of `8bits`(256) if the code <= 256 it is `8bits` char else it is not. And I will do so with `16bits`, `32bits` etc...

Comment: @HoangNguyen There would be no 32bits, as `char` is only 16 bits. Comparing to 256 is as good as masking with `0xff00`, use whichever you prefer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, "There would be no 32bits" so how about UTF-32 I am understading that 32 is 32bits, am I wrong?

Comment: @HoangNguyen Java's `char` is fixed size, it's 16 bits, so as far as Jaca `char` goes, there is no UTF-8 or UTF-32.